# GulpJS: Ignoring glob match on output

Tags: glob, gulp

I am currently trying to match several folders with glob by doing:

```
gulp.src('workbench/fdw/**/public/admin/images/**')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/admin/images/'))
```

This works perfectly but the output ends up being something like:

```
public/assets/admin/images/core/public/admin/images/*
```

and I would like the first glob to not be preserved and look like:

```
public/assets/admin/images/*
```

Anyone know how I can change my glob to work like that? I do need the first wildcard because there is an unknown amount of folders that will be getting used.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but I don't know your complete file structure.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var gulpIgnore = require('gulp-ignore');

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function(){
    var common = 'public/admin/images';
    return gulp.src('workbench/fdw/**/public/admin/images/**')
    //this renames the image files
    .pipe(rename(function(path){
            var offset = path.dirname.indexOf(common);
            if (offset !== -1) {
                path.dirname = path.dirname.substring(offset+common.length+1);
            }
            return path;
     }))
    //this strips out the directories before the images files
    .pipe(gulpIgnore.include(function(file){
            return file.path.indexOf(common) === -1;
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/admin/images/'));
});
```

It is a two step process.  The rename step corrects the file names so that the output is what you expect.  The problem is `gulp.src` sends more than what we want.  It includes all of parent directories.  By keeping only this step, the output will contain directories such as `foo/public/admin/images/` which will result in `public/assets/admin/images/foo/public/admin/images/`.  The ignore step is to filter those extra directories out.